# Function that takes in a meshgrid of values

Tags: python, numpy

I want a function that takes in 2 numbers and a matrix and does a multiplication operation using them and then sums every element of the matrix after multiplication (see code below).

I am trying to do this operation for all possible combinations of x and y. What is the best way to do this without using loops, since I know I could loop over the function with different values of x and y but this doesn't seem like an efficient way to do it.

I tried using a meshgrid as input but that didnt work due to the way the input is broadcasted.

```
import numpy as np

def my_func(num1, num2, matrix2):
    return np.sum(matrix*num1*num2)

x = np.linspace(0,5)
y = np.linspace(0,1)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
matrix = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])

a = my_func(X,Y,matrix)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (50,50) (3,1)
```

I would like `a` to equal a meshgrid of values where each value in the array corresponds to the output of `my_func` for every possible combination of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Please provide some example input and some example output.

Comment: @Kraigolas I added the output I get after running the code if this is what you mean.

Comment: what I mean to say is, provide some examples of what you are trying to get as `a`. It's a bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Kraigolas I edited my equation so my goal is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `x * y * M` when `x` and `y` are scalar is just `M.shape`. If you want this result for each value of `x` and `y`, you will want a result of shape `x.shape + y.shape + M.shape`. You can do this with broadcasting for the totally general case. The idea is that you need to reshape `x` to have trailing ones too fill in `y.ndim + M.ndim` dimensions and `y` to have `M.ndim` trailing dimensions.

For the sake of the summation, it's actually easier to ravel `M`, even though [`np.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) allows for multiple axes since version 1.7.0.

```
def my_func(x, y, matrix):
    x = np.reshape(x, x.shape + (1,) * (y.ndim + 1))
    y = np.reshape(y, y.shape + (1,))
    return (x * y * matrix.ravel()).sum(axis=-1)
```

If you want to input `x` and `y` that are already broadcasted together, you can adjust the calculation slightly:

```
def my_func(x, y, matrix):
    return ((x * y)[:, None] * matrix.ravel()).sum(-1)
```

The conceptual difference is that the first version accepts the `linspace`s you created directly, while the second version requires you to construct the `meshgrid`, or at least transpose one of the arrays.

Comment: I have edited my question so it is more clear what kind of output I am looking for.

Comment: @NahPlsMan. Cool. I updated with the sum. Try running what I posted and let me know if it works.

Comment: I ran the code and it worked well thank you. However, is some way of having meshgrids X and Y as inputs to the function and have the function produce a meshgrid of values. I am thinking of something similar to what np.vectorize does whereby the function takes each argument from an input array and uses to it calculate the return.

Comment: @NahPlsMan. I've added a version that accepts a meshgrid.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to adjust the dimensions of your `x` and `y` array:

```
import numpy as np

def my_func(num1, num2, matrix2):
    return matrix*num1*num2

x = np.linspace(0,5, num=3)
y = np.linspace(0,1, num=3)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
matrix = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])

a = my_func(X,Y,matrix)
print(a)
# [[ 0.   0.   0. ]
#  [ 0.   2.5  5. ]
#  [ 0.   7.5 15. ]]
```

Comment: I have changed my question slightly due to my question not being clear enough.